# NgMatero DateTimePicker showing different behavior in components

Tags: angular, angular-material, datetimepicker, angular-forms

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-placeholder>DateTime</mat-placeholder>
    <mtx-datetimepicker-toggle [for]="datetimePicker" matSuffix></mtx-datetimepicker-toggle>
    <mtx-datetimepicker #datetimePicker [timeInterval]="5" type="date"></mtx-datetimepicker>
    <input
        [mtxDatetimepicker]="datetimePicker"
        autocomplete="false"
        matInput
        required
        (dateChange)="onDateChange($event.value)"
        value="2023-06-19"
    />
</mat-form-field>
```

Added above code, within ts no change have added.
Versions used:

```
"@angular/core": "14.2.12",
"@angular/material": "14.2.7",
"@ng-matero/extensions": "14.2.2",
```

sharing behaviour on 2 components implemented

1. On the first , when I add "1" in the input and press tab or replicate a blur event (click out of the datepicker) an mtxdatetimeparse error is thrown.

```
<date-time-picker
    type="date"
    [control]="value"
></date-time-picker>
```

2. On the second , when I add "1" in the input and press tab or replicate a blur event, date gets converted to [image: date object].

```
<date-time-picker type="date" 
  formControlName="dateInserted"
  [control]="form.get('dateInserted')"
  (valueChange)="onDateChange($event)">
</date-time-picker>
```

Tried downgrading the version.

Was expecting consistent behavior in both the components , but was showing above different behavior on different components

Comment: `[control]="value"` seems odd. is `value` a FormControl ??

Comment: value = new UntypedFormControl('')